# How to turn anything into a button in Android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, tablerow, nested

I need a way of turning a `TableRow` into a `Button` in android. I have tried to set up an `onCLickListener()` and I have tried nesting a `TableRow` inside a `Button` but that just crashes the app.

**Edit:**

I deleted the android:onCLick="onClick" like you said and that got rid of the crashing but nothing happens when I click the table row.

My code:

```
tableRow1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent openInfoTR1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MENU");
        fromTableRow = 1;
        startActivity(openInfoTR1);


System.out.println("Confirmed click");
    }
});
```

---

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlDisplayTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trTableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:visibility="invisible"                
            android:clickable="true">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDisplayedText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:layout_weight="5"/>
         </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, logcat and xml as well?

Comment: post your code and logcat please ?

Comment: As you've now posted code and log cat, I've extended my answer with a fix to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Every element that inherits from `View` can have attached an `OnClickListener`. No need to wrap it inside a button.

However, you'll have to look at how events are propagated through your layout. E.g. if you have clickable elements within your TableRow, the click events will normally be consumed by that elements and will not reach your `OnClickListener`. There are different ways to intercept or modify that behaviour, but you'd have to post your code to get more specific help.

**EDIT:**

The exception in your app comes from the line `android:onClick="onClick"` in your layout file. As you set the onClick listener programmatically, you do not need this. `android:onClick="onClick"` is a shortcut that would expect a method `void onClick(View view)` directly within your Activity (not, as you have it, as part of the `OnClickListener`  implementation).